# Cannot execute JSON.parse() under 1.10.2/jquery.min.js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

It is work if I use the JSON.parse() to parse the PHP array return  if applying 1.3.2/jquery.min.js but not 1.10.2/jquery.min.js, do anyone have similar experience and solution?

PHP array return

```
$returnArray['vercode'] = FALSE;
echo json_encode($returnArray);
```

AJAX call

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: $('#form1').serialize(),
    url: $('#form1').attr('action'),
    complete: function (HttpRequest, textStatus) {
        $obj = JSON.parse("HttpRequest.response");
    }
});
```

Comment: why parsing a parsed one?

Answer (score 4):

First, you parse the string "HttpRequest.response", remove the quotes. Then, as you set the dataType to "json", you don't have to parse it to get an array.

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false, 
    type: "POST", 
    dataType: "json",
    data: $('#form1').serialize(),
    url: $('#form1').attr('action'),
    complete: function (HttpRequest, textStatus) {
        $obj = HttpRequest.response;
  }});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use instead:

```
$obj = JSON.parse(HttpRequest.response);
```

`JSON.parse("HttpRequest.response");` will give you an error because you try to parse a string: `"HttpRequest.response"`.

Also, probably you don't need to use `JSON.parse()` because the content is already parsed by jQuery using `dataType: "json"`:

```
$obj = HttpRequest.response;
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be use instead:

```
$obj = JSON.parse(HttpRequest.responseText);
```

HttpRequest.response is same as HttpRequest.responseText and fine if not specify the dataType as json but not correct Property (http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_response.asp)